# echo inside dynamic created div-tag php javascript

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

Im trying to echo an xml value to an dynamic created div tag, but i cant seem to find any information about it.

The DOM tree is created with JavaScript

```
textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
```

The output become `<textarea></textarea>`No problem here... 
Then Im getting the value from an xml file with simple php.

```
<?php
foreach($xml->sticker as $sticker ){
$post = $sticker->text . "</br>";
$post;

echo $post;
}
?>
```

and the echo returns " Hello World "

Now to the issue, how do I echo inside the dynamically created textarea
the output should be
`<textarea>Hello world</textarea>`

Any ideas ? or a link maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you getting in result at the moment?

Comment: php is processed before you create any html element. So the only idea i get right now, is to echo php into hidden input, or `display: none` div, and then with javascript, use this value to fill newly created textarea. OR you AJAX

Comment: document.append("<textarea>"+$post+"</textarea>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you successfully load the xml with XHR then you can put your response inside your textarea with:

```
textArea.innerHTML = responseFromXHR;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear on how your application is supposed to work. If you want to fetch the data using ajax or not. Some people here seems to think so although you haven't stated that. I will assume that is not the case. If it is the solution would most likely be to have you `PHP` script return `JSON` encoded data, decode that using `Javascript` and insert it into the `textarea`.

Since you dynamically create the `textarea` you also have to dynamicly fill it with text using `Javascript`. Just add the text to the `.innerHTML` of the textarea.

Some `if` check in PHP to make sure the text should be printed and that the `textarea` exists and then using PHP add this to a Javascript.

```
echo 'textArea.innerHTML = "' . $post;
```

If you are supposed to print all `posts` in the same `textarea`you could do something like

```
<?php
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'textArea = document.createElement(\'textarea\');';
  foreach($xml->sticker as $sticker ){
    $posts .= $sticker->text . "\n\r";
    echo $post;
  }

  echo 'textArea.innerHTML = "' . $posts;
  echo '</script>';
?>
```

You could also have the check for the `textarea's` existence in Javascript if you'd like that. You probably wan't to do some filtering on the text you put into the `textarea` though.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the value from the XML file?

In the PHP, return a string or JSON object, then in the AJAX callback, insert the data into the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Your php script that returns "Hello World" must be called via AJAX and on successful answer just like 'apelsinapa' said:

```
textArea.innerHTML = responseFromAjaxCall;
```

Otherwise - the PHP code gets parsed by the server before JavaScript creates the textarea node.

Comment: and by the way - if you want to add line breaks to your textarea, the you should echo '\n\r' instead of '<br />' :-)